# Cant access images in /pub/media/customer

Tags: customer, url, permissions, media-images

I have added custom attribute for profile image upload. Now when i access customer image on front end it shows 404 error and donot access images in this folder /pub/media/customer .

Comment: check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/197737/20064

Comment: @piyush i am already doing this my question is images in this folders are not accessed.

Comment: If it is returning 404 error then it means, your image does not exist at the given path or you may have provided wrong path , you can also check the permission of the directory

Comment: image is placed in this path. i am able to acceess pub/media/catalog/product images .

Comment: but unable to access images in customer folder it shows "The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why." and 404 error when i access them from mobile application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve this issue after configuring htaccess.conf file in server which is placed on this directory of server /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/conf
Note : server i am using is bitname server.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove .htaccess from pub/media/customer and image start loading at front-end.

Answer (score 1):

I have resloved this issue with

> pub/media/customer

on nginx server after change option on nginx.config.sample on root magento folder.

```
#location /media/customer/ {
#   deny all;
#}
```

then reload nginx and restart nginx service. Good luck!